# DLL: File format not recognised when compiling C with MinGW on Linux for Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, dll, mingw

I'm using MinGW on Linux (Ubuntu, specifically) to compile a C program for Windows. I'm using a library called SFML, and it's bindings called CSFML. I'm using -L and -l to locate the libraries, but when I compile I get this error:

```
win32/dll/csfml-audio-2.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognised
```

I've got no idea why. Here's the command I'm using to compile:

```
sudo i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o wandering src/main.c src/constants.c src/Display/display.c **...some more c files in here...** src/Generation/perlinnoise.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0) $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gee-1.0) -Iwin32/CSFML-2.1/include -Lwin32/dll -lcsfml-audio-
```

Does anyone know why it's happening? I can compile C programs without SFML but with MinGW just fine...

Comment: your compile statement is using 'relative' directory path, I think it should be an absolute path.  I.E. -I/win32/CSFML-2.1/include -L/win32/dll

Answer (score 5):

The DLL has a PE32 executable file header. It's not used for the linker. You should use the import library instead. This file has the extension LIB.

I heard there are some gcc compiler versions out there than generate an import library from a DLL on the fly. It looks like your version doesn't.

Comment: Import library? What's that? What file extension do they have?

Comment: Actually for mingw, import libraries should have the same extension as archives `lib*.a`. Sometimes, `lib*.dll.a` is used to distinguish between an import lib and an archive containing actual code.

Comment: `It looks like your version doesn't` — I don't think that's what happens. The other answer here turned out to work for me, you just need to use a mingw with different bitness. After that link stage finished no problem.

Answer (score 1):

From command line it seem's trying to use sudo i686-**w64**-mingw32-gcc 64 bit compiler and supplying 32 bit DLL i.e. **win32**/dll/csfml-audio-2.dll. change to **x64**/dll/csfml-audio-2.dll. It should work fine.

Comment: It seems like by using `file` command on a dll, you may see if it's 32 bit: `…PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386…` or 64 bit: `…PE32+ executable (DLL) (console) x86-64…`