# How to compile a dll which needs other dlls

Tags: c, dll, makefile, linker, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile a piece of software I'm doing.
I'm on Linux and I'm having a pretty hard time trying to write a Makefile for compiling a DLL library using SDL2. Here is it:

```
#the compiler
CC = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc

#the standart ompilation flags of the project
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

#path to the folder's root, where the holy not build framework is. Relate to this Makefile
PREPATH = ..

#Path to the SDL, SDL_image and Lua includes and libs
SDL2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)/SDL2/include
SDL2LIBS = $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/SDL2.dll
SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)/SDL2/SDL_image
SDLIMAGE2LIBS = $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/SDL2_image.dll $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libjpeg-9.dll $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libpng16-16.dll $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libtiff-5.dll $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libwebp-4.dll $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/zlib1.dll
#LUAINCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)/lua/
#LUALIB = $(PREPATH)/lua/ -llua -lm

#Where to put the compiled program
COMPILEPATH = $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/



#Build options

build: NLF.o
    cp ./*.o $(COMPILEPATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $(COMPILEPATH)libNLF.dll $(SDL2LIBS) $(SDLIMAGE2LIBS) $(COMPILEPATH)*.o

NLF.o: NLF_osservice.o NLF_error.o NLF_screen.o NLF.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF.c
NLF.h.gch: NLF.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF.h

NLF_osservice.o: NLF_osservice.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_osservice.c
NLF_osservice.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_osservice.h

NLF_error.o: NLF_error.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_error.c
NLF_error.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_error.h

NLF_screen.o: NLF_screen.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF_screen.c
NLF_screen.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF_screen.h



#cleaning options

clean-build:
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o

clean-all:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o $(COMPILEPATH)*.so

clean-soft:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o
```

When running make all, the compilation runs fine, but when it gets to the `-shared` part, I get this:

> ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/SDL2.dll: file not recognized:

I tried to add `-L` before the Third Party DLL, like this:

```
SDL2LIBS = -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/SDL2.dll
SDLIMAGE2LIBS = -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/SDL2_image.dll -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libjpeg-9.dll -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libpng16-16.dll -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libtiff-5.dll -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libwebp-4.dll -L $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/zlib1.dll
```

And then I get undefined reference errors...
The same error if I change the line:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared -o $(COMPILEPATH)libNLF.dll $(SDL2LIBS) $(SDLIMAGE2LIBS) $(COMPILEPATH)*.o
```

for

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2LIBS) $(SDLIMAGE2LIBS) -shared -o $(COMPILEPATH)libNLF.dll $(COMPILEPATH)*.o
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use -L before library files. -L indicates a library path. For library files, you should use -l (lowercase L).
But, if you're indicating the path to the file, and are including the file extension, you don't need to use -l, though. So the initial Makefile was correct in that sense.

You should provide the full error that you got, not `just file not recognized:`. I bet this is a `file format not recognized` error, which probably indicates that you should not be linking against a .dll file, but .lib files. [Similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191258/dll-file-format-not-recognised-when-compiling-c-with-mingw-on-linux-for-windows).

Comment: yes, it is a "file format not recognized" error: ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/SDL2.dll: file not recognized: Formato de arquivo não reconhecido

Comment: I think I understood the error, the binaries .dll file must be delivered with the final application. For the compiler I should link the .a and .dll.a files...
I'm just curious about one thing, for linux I use the .a and the .so files. But for windows only the .a?... I'll try it out anyway.

Comment: Here is what a tried: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -shared -o ../BINARIES/libNLF.dll ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/libSDL2.a ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/libSDL2.dll.a ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/libSDL2main.a ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2/64/libSDL2_test.a ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libSDL2_image.a ../BINARIES/4windows/SDL2_image/64/libSDL2_image.dll.a
 || I got a bunch of undefined reference errors to the SDL functions

Comment: On linux, even if you use .so files to link a program, you must have the .so files bundled with the application (or have your environment variables set so that the SO can have a clue where to search those .so files). Those are called shared libraries. A library that ends with .a is called a static library and its functions are "copied" into the final binary.

Comment: If you are still having undefined references, then you are missing library files.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved!! here is how
Putting these files within the SDL path:

> libSDL2.a, libSDL2.dll.a, libSDL2main.a, libSDL2_test.a, SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib, and SDL2test.lib

And these with the SDL_image one.:

> libSDL2_image.a and libSDL2_image.dll.a

And here is the Makefile:

```
#the compiler
CC = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc

#the standart ompilation flags of the project
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

#path to the folder's root, where the holy not build framework is. Relate to this Makefile
PREPATH = ..

#Path to the SDL, SDL_image and Lua includes and libs
SDL2INCLUDES = -I $DS(PREPATH)/SDL2/include
SDL2LIBS = -L$(PREPATH)/SDL2/4windows/SDL2/64 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)/SDL2/SDL_image
SDLIMAGE2LIBS = -L$(PREPATH)/SDL2/4windows/SDL2_image/64 -lSDL2_image
#LUAINCLUDES = -I $(PREPATH)/lua/
#LUALIB = -L $(PREPATH)/lua/ -llua -lm

#Where to put the compiled program
COMPILEPATH = $(PREPATH)/BINARIES/



#Build options

build: NLF.o
    cp ./*.o $(COMPILEPATH)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(COMPILEPATH)*.o $(SDL2LIBS) $(SDLIMAGE2LIBS) -o $(COMPILEPATH)libNLF.dll

NLF.o: NLF_osservice.o NLF_error.o NLF_screen.o NLF.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF.c
NLF.h.gch: NLF.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF.h

NLF_osservice.o: NLF_osservice.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_osservice.c
NLF_osservice.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_osservice.h

NLF_error.o: NLF_error.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_error.c
NLF_error.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) NLF_error.h

NLF_screen.o: NLF_screen.h.gch
    $(CC) -c -DBUILD_DLL $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF_screen.c
NLF_screen.h.gch:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDL2INCLUDES) $(SDLIMAGE2INCLUDES) NLF_screen.h



#cleaning options

clean-build:
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o

clean-all:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o $(COMPILEPATH)*.dll

clean-soft:
    rm -f -v ./*.o ./*.h.gch
    rm -f -v $(COMPILEPATH)*.o
```

Now my new problem is how to compile all this stuff to 32 bits windows. But it is an statement for another question.

Comment: I've notice that the  i686-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler compiles to 32bits platform! To compile for 64bits use: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler. Both come if you install: apt-get install mingw-w64
Of course you'll need the correspondent 32 and 64 libs in each case.